# Android: Programatically changing phone settings and getting lost calls

Tags: android, registry

Is it possible in Android to programatically change the phone internet settings (proxies also), email settings and other similar? Is there some kind of registry?

and what about getting the lost/received/etc calls? is it possible to get that info?

Answer (score 0):

> anybody knows if it's possible in
>   Android to programatically change the
>   phone internet settings (proxies
>   also), email settings and other
>   similar? Is there some kind of
>   registry?

`android.provider.Settings.System` and `android.net.wifi.WifiManager` have what is available.

> and what about getting the
>   lost/received/etc calls? is it
>   possible to get that info?

```
android.provider.CallLog
```

Comment: hi there,

thanks for the info, i didn't notice provider package.. regarding email, is it possible to have push email using other service than gmail?